# Android Package name changes when building an app from a Flutter Module

Tags: android, flutter, build

I'm having a small problem. I'm trying to build an apk from a flutter module. I specified:

```
module:
    androidX: true
    androidPackage: com.my.package.name
```

The issue is that after I run flutter pub get, the applicationId is set to com.my.package.name.host.
I'd like to remove the .host part somehow as I'm trying to automate this and upload it to Firebase app distribution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Vlad

Comment: you have to give same name as you give in firebase (package id)

Comment: that works! but then I would like to update an existing android app with this flutter app and will have to keep the same application id as the old app.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
lane :change_package_name do
    path = "../../.android/app/build.gradle"
    text = File.read(path)
    updated = text.gsub(".host", "")
    File.open(path, "w") { |file| file.puts updated }
end
```

it's a small fastlane script that removes the occurance of .host. Not the best solution but it works for now.